# How to delete static library ".a" file from xcode project?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I created a Cocoa Touch Static Library in Xcode. Now I want to delete it from my project as I realized I don't need it anymore.
I deleted all the ".h" and ".m" files as well as the supporting "info.plist" file of the static library, but am unable to delete "StaticLibrary.a" and "StaticLibraryTests.xctest" file from Products group of Xcode. Kindly help.

Comment: Why you can't? What happens when you try?

Comment: When I right click on it, the "delete" option is shown disabled.